# Не работает append()

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
$("body").delegate(".click_for_fetch", "click", function () {
            var request = { id: $(this).attr('path-id') };
            $.ajax({
                url: "Handler1.ashx",
                data: request,
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",

                success: function (obj) {
                    $("#"+request.id).append(obj.Str);
                }
            });
        });
```

Запрос от сервера приходит с кодом 200, все ок. Вот только проблема с `append()` почему то не добавляются новые теги.

Comment: чему равно `$("#"+request.id).length`?

Comment: _As of jQuery 1.7, .delegate() has been superseded by the .on() method._, какую версию jQuery вы используете?

Comment: есть ли вообще элемент с таким ид?

Comment: версия jquery-1.11.3.js

Comment: Такой Id есть вот пример тега                                                                 <li class="click_for_fetch" path-id="C:\\Down" id="C:\\Down"><a>C:\\Down</a></li>

Comment: $("#"+request.id).length равен 0...

Comment: если `jquery-1.11.3.js` то вместо `delegate` лучше `on` используй.

Comment: если _$("#"+request.id).length равен 0_ значит элемента с таким ид - нет

Comment: попробуйте использовать другой id, [ссылка на вопрос о допустимых символах в css-селекторах](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/448981/which-characters-are-valid-in-css-class-names-selectors)

Comment: или экранируйте невалидные символы

Comment: Grundy спасибо, получилось, я просто из id убрал символы : и \

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как выяснилось из комментариев - проблема в id элемента. Некоторые символы запрещено напрямую использовать в селекторах, и их нужно экранировать.

В данном случае:

```
C:\\Down
```

нужно экранировать, как минимум, обратные слеши: `C:\\\\Down`, тогда элемент можно будет получить с помощью функции `document.getElementById`
как максимум экранировать еще раз все вместе с двоеточием, для текущего примера будет:

```
'#C\\3A \\\\\\\\Down'
```

Отличный сайт показывающий пример как будет выглядеть экранированный селектор: https://mothereff.in/css-escapes#0C%3A%5C%5CDown

либо как вариант - просто убрать такие символы.