# Допускается ли русскоязычное значение атрибута name ссылки <a>?

Tags: html

Допустим, есть сайт с русскоязычным доменным именем, но мы хотим, чтобы любой URL, включающий рассматриваемый домен, был тоже русскоязычным. Это значит, что любые ссылки внутри сайта должны быть тоже русскоязычными.

Если имена CSS-классов и ID могут быть заданы только латинскими буквами и цифрами, то можно ли задавать русскоязычное значение атрибута `name` для ссылки `<a>`? Этим самым можно будет добиться URL типа:

```
www.русскоязычныйсайт.рф/статьи/кошки/рэгдолл#характер
```

То есть к заголовку "рэгдолл" будет добавлено `<a name="характер"></a>`.

Неприемлемость таких URL на интернациональных сайтах конкретно в этом вопрсе рассматривать не будем.

Comment: «имена CSS-классов и ID могут быть заданы только латинскими буквами и цифрами» — нет, они могут содержать абсолютно любые символы (в том числе русские), кроме пробелов

Comment: [Other than _isindex_, **any non-empty value** for name is allowed.](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#naming-form-controls:-the-name-attribute)

Comment: Серьёзно? Это замечательно, особенно если препроцессоры и JS будут нормально с ними работать. Тогда, получается, и никакие ссылки с name не нужны.

Comment: @GurebuBokofu, немного про селекторы и доступы к ним из скрипта в [связанном вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/468650/186999)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Упоминания атрибута `name` у тега `<a>` я в стандарте HTML5 вообще не нашёл. Он был в HTML4, однако в HTML5 вместо него предлагается использовать `id`. Валидатор пишет предупреждение, что атрибут устаревший, но на русские буквы внутри не ругается, так что, наверно, ответ — можно, но не нужно.

`class` и `id` не имеют ограничений, которые вы указали в вопросе. Вольно перевожу [стандарт](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute):

> Значение должно быть уникальным среди всех элементов, имеющих ID, и должно иметь хотя бы один символ. Значение не может содержать никакие пробельные символы.
>
> Заметка: Кроме этого больше никаких других ограничений на ID нет; в частности, ID может содержать одни лишь числа, начинаться с числа или с подчёркивания, состоять только из знаков препинания и т.д.

Ограничения на русские буквы нигде не указано, да и валидатор не ругается.

С классами примерно аналогично, но про них стандарт написан чуть более запутанно. (Да-да, в классах помимо русских букв можно ещё использовать точки, звёздочки и другие спецсимволы, только с ними потом работать неудобно :)